# Is there a difference between the dll in bin versus the published dll in vs2012

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, visual-studio-2012

If I clean my project under release. And then I build the project under release. And then I take that `.dll` from from the `bin` is that file going to be any different than the `.dll` generated from using the **Publish** feature with "Release" selected?

Comment: 1. What makes you think they're different and 2. Why does it matter?

Comment: @DStanley - I was unsure if they were different, and it seemed important to be cautious about not accidentally deploying an incorrect `.dll`.

Comment: Couldn't the result be different when you select `PreCompile` when publishing? This is more a retorical question.

Comment: @Silvermind - That is not the situation I was referring to. However, the result would most definitely be different when using any of the precompiling settings, especially the ones which include the `.cshtml` files.

Comment: That's what I meant ;) It's just sort of a reminder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not an expert reading MSBuild files, but it looks like there's no difference at all because it looks like that's exactly what MSBuild..

You can pull up "%windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Microsoft.Common.targets", find the Publish target, and trace through the dependencies to eventually find the _CopyFilesToPublishFolder target which does exactly what it says: copy everything covered by the OutputFiles property (among a bunch of other files) to the publish directory.

Answer (score 1):

Well, providing that nothing in the source code changes, then yes it should be the same.  If something in the source (or a dependency) changes, then VS will likely rebuild the project before publishing.